# Cannot use replace method on python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanted to change my variables on spesific column with dictionary values but it does not change. I tried several ways and but it does not work. My dataset has 47k rows and my dictionary has 30 different words so I will show some.

My dataset:

[image: My dataset]

Dictionary:

```
rolechange = {"\\Adv":"Adversary",
          "\\Sci":"Scientist",
          "\\Inn":"Innocent",
          "\\Und":"Undetermined"}
```

I'm trying

```
movies_df["Role Type"].replace(rolechange, inplace=True)
```

It does not gives error but result is same. I couldn't find similar question on here, sorry for if its duplicate.

Comment: Is possible get list from problematic column values? Like `print (movies_df["Role Type"].head(10).tolist())`

Comment: It prints: ['\\\\Sci', '\\\\Inn', '\\\\Und', '\\\\Und', '\\\\Und', '\\\\Und', '\\\\Und', '\\\\Und', '\\\\Und', '\\\\Und']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create `raw strings` (prefix `'r'`)

```
rolechange = {r"\\Adv":"Adversary",
              r"\\Sci":"Scientist",
              r"\\Inn":"Innocent",
              r"\\Und":"Undetermined"}

>>> df['Role Type'].replace(rolechange)

0       Scientist
1        Innocent
2    Undetermined
Name: Role Type, dtype: object
```